# Installing cppman

Tags: fedora, vim, linux-mint, software-installation, python

I've tried to install [cppman](https://github.com/Aitjcize/cppman) in Fedora 19 or Linux mint 15 and it installs successfully. But when I try to use it I get the error:

```
Python IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I've installed it in Ubuntu 12.04 and had no problem.

Update: I fixed this problem, but I have a new problem. when for example I enter `cppman cout` the output shown is not in right format:

```
1mNAME0m
       std::cout - Standard output stream

1mTYPE0m
       object
       <iostream>
1mSYNOPSIS0m
       extern ostream cout;

1mDESCRIPTION0m
       Object of class ostream that represents the standard output stream oriented to narrow characters (of type
         char


       ). It corresponds to the C stream stdout.
```

It seems that I need to install or configure something.

Comment: Is that really the complete error? No backtrace?

Comment: @Gilles: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: What method did you use to install cppman? `pip install` or was it a RPM in the repository?

Comment: Gilles is referrring to a TraceBack which is a path through the code that was running when the error was encountered. You can see an example in this SO Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246114/python-ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied

Comment: @slm: with `pip install`

Comment: @slm: I fixed that problem but now I have new problem. (see update)

Comment: I tried to clean up the question a bit, can you fix the text of the output so that it's correct? For example, is it wrapped in double quotes?